# React App continually shows as loading in Chrome browser on localhost

Tags: reactjs, localhost

I have a react app, that continually shows as loading when run on local host. As in the page loads completely and all the network calls are resolved and works as expected, but it still has the spinner on the tab name. However if I manually refresh the page after the initial load it will then show as fully loaded.

It works fine in other browsers, and in other environments.

The issue with this is when running cypress tests they fail as they wait for the "load" event to fire, which it does not.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. But somehow upgrading Chrome fixed it for me.